# Continuous and discrete joint probability

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, marginal-probability

[image]

i have attempted parts a ) b ) to which is in the link https://ibb.co/LQnztn0 however i cannot seem to understand parts c) and d )

my attempt to try part c) but then got stuck https://ibb.co/9pm0D8J